# Match HTTP_FILTER to a specific service in Istio

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I have a EnvoyFilter like below, I dont have a workload selector and need this http filter to be applied to all the sidecars. But I want the http filter to apply only when specific service/service entry is called. Is there a way to do this ?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: headers-envoy-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.router
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
         inline_code: |
           function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
             request_handle:headers():add("custom-header", "hello")
           end

           function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
             response_handle:headers():add("custom-header", "hello")
           end
```